# Is there any way to clean space/memory from emulator?

Tags: android

[2012-04-18 23:20:03 - MyVideo] Failed to install MyVideo.apk on device 'emulator-5554': No space left on device

[2012-04-18 23:20:03 - MyVideo] com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: No space left on device

Comment: I'm getting the same error, too, and I have deleted just about everything on there that I can.  The problem fixes itself when I restart the emulator, which is time consuming.  It's only good for about three or four installs of any given app, and then I have to restart.

Comment: got your issue solved or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a bigger sd card and install them to that?

Answer (score 2):

Just delete/uninstall other apps from your emulator.

Inside the emulator go to the Settings app, then Applications -> Manage Applications -- you can delete them from there.

To increase sd card size in ecllipse goto windows->AVD manager-> select your avd name -> click edit-> enter size and click on edit AVD.

Also refer this [LINK](http://www.swfgeek.net/2011/09/07/quicktip-uninstall-your-android-app-from-the-avd-emulator/) to delete app  from command prompt

Comment: In the manage applications I donot see any apps of considerable size, I mean with a few kbs, still it is showing the same error!

Comment: Increase your  sd card size and install them to that?

Comment: while creting emulator you can specify the size also or edit you AVD and specify the size as 128Mb or 256Mb depending on your requirement

Comment: I have no idea how to do that in an emulator?

Comment: Are you talking about the VM heap size?

Comment: yes, i am using eclipse, where do i need to specify the sd card size?

Comment: Ok, saw it, actually never needed to specify that, so didn't know it was the sd card. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2):

delete the cache or data of the application

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to wipe the data?

Go to AVD Manager from Actions table → Select down arrow → choose Wipe Data

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple. Goto AVD Manager. Then Click an option on Device that you want to clear its storage > Wipe Data

DONE

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its tedius and slow to have to remove apps every time. Instead, make your app install to the emulator SD card (which can have gigabytes of space).

Look in your android manifest and make sure you have enabled install to SD card.

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html